# Firebird server 2.5 Update query is too slow

Tags: sql, windows, firebird

I have a Firebird database. The database file is about 80 MB. I have a varchar(2000) column and I want only update this column. 
My exact query is :

```
 UPDATE PATIENTS SET IPADLIST = ''
```

In the PATIENTS table there are only 55000 patients.
The server has a Core I7 processor and an SSD and 8 GB of memory.

But the query takes almost 10 minutes!
During the execution of the query, the disk usage is 100%.

The extension of the database file was .GDB and I found that Windows monitors some extensions :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378870(v=vs.85).aspx

I changed the extension to .FDB but it doesn't change the result.

The script of the creation of the table :

```
 CREATE TABLE PATIENTS
 (
   NOM Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   PRENOM Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   N_CLIENT Integer NOT NULL,
   D_NAISSANCE Date,
   SEX Varchar(1) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RUE Varchar(255) COLLATE FR_FR,
   BATIMENT Varchar(255) COLLATE FR_FR,
   CODEVILLE Varchar(75) COLLATE FR_FR,
   NOM_A Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   PRENOM_A Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   TEL_1 Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   TEL_2 Varchar(25) COLLATE FR_FR,
   SPORT_1 Varchar(50) COLLATE FR_FR,
   SPORT_2 Varchar(50) COLLATE FR_FR,
   PROFESSION Varchar(75) COLLATE FR_FR,
   MEDECIN_1 Varchar(30) COLLATE FR_FR,
   MEDECIN_2 Varchar(30) COLLATE FR_FR,
   ENVORER Varchar(30) COLLATE FR_FR,
   MEMO Blob sub_type 1,
   MEMOI Blob sub_type 1,
   MEMO_CLE Blob sub_type 1,
   RQUE1 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE2 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE3 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE4 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   NUM_SPORT1 Integer,
   NUM_SPORT2 Integer,
   NUM_MEDECIN1 Integer,
   NUM_MEDECIN2 Integer,
   RQUE5 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE6 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE7 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE8 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE9 Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   RQUE10 Varchar(200) COLLATE FR_FR,
   CODE_POSTAL Varchar(10) COLLATE FR_FR,
   NUM_PROFESSION Integer,
   CIVILITE Varchar(50) COLLATE FR_FR,
   EMAIL Varchar(100) COLLATE FR_FR,
   NUM_VILLE Integer,
   NUM_MEDECIN3 Integer,
   IPADLIST Varchar(1000),
   UPDATEDDATE Timestamp,
   ID_EPODO Integer,
   PRIMARY KEY (N_CLIENT)
 );
 CREATE INDEX NOM ON PATIENTS (NOM);
 GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON PATIENTS TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148116/discussion-on-question-by-coskun-ozogul-firebird-server-2-5-update-query-is-too).

Answer (score 1):

This db structure has not really good performance (a lot of field of blob type and varchar). If you update one field unconditionally firebird will create huge temporary files to proceed the query.
If you can change structure to move IPADLIST to another table it could increase speed.
for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE IPADS (
ID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
IPADLIST    VARCHAR(1000),
PATIENT_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE IPADS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_IPADS PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE IPADS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_IPADS_PATIENTS_ID FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_ID) REFERENCES PATIENTS (N_CLIENT) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and remove ipdadlist from patients

then, if patient add an iPad u will just insert it to the iPads table by patient's N_CLIENT
and instead of updating u need just delete from iPads by required N_CLIENT or all

Comment: It was an existing database and I don't know what is wrong whit it. It doesn't work on my pc neighter on the server of the client. So, I found another solution. I keep synchronised IDs in another database because I don't want to recreate the same database and import all existing datas.

Answer (score 1):

*This should be a comment, but I want to show the picture*

From your comment:

> There are real performance problems in Firebird. As a solution, I
>   created an sqlite database file and I keep IPadIDs in this database.
>   It works.

This is the result from test with your table (55000 records).

On my laptop Core I5 processor and 8 GB of memory.

Firebird version 2.5.5.

Database charset : ISO8859_1

[image]

Comment: OK.  And? . . . . . .

Comment: @RobertHarvey  He thinks that `There are real performance problems in Firebird.` See the comment after another answer. It would be good if he knew it was not.

Comment: I assume you don't have any insight beyond the test you performed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey On the contrary, I have been working with Fierebird for many years and I know there is no problem with productivity, especially with "updatе". I really do not know what is happening on his computer (and there is no way to know) but to say that there is a problem with Fiberbird just because something is not done(or is done), is not correct, because it can be mislead someone who will read this question. Good night.

Comment: I appologize, you are right, I am going to change my comment. It was a quick comment after a long search and I was tired and I couldn't explain properly.

Comment: you probably use SuperServer and maybe even with cache-increased configuration ( or with extra cache set in the database file properties ).  Assuming std 4KB page size, you seem to write to the HDD about 24 MB, while reading about 32 MB. Now, if we would reduce caches to Classic Server levels it might go exponential I think. Also, maybe CO's HDD was heavily fragmented.

Comment: "He thinks that There are real performance problems in Firebird" - well, there are. In any practical software there are compromises and hard choices. And those choices can be problems, if using the tool wrong way. It is just a property of EVERY practical software. And function of your method of using it and your definition what "problem" is. This claim is trivially true. "There is always room for invention".